# Using FreeBase to retrieve sports teams by league

Tags: json, freebase, mql

As shown here http://tinyurl.com/kw2z65f I am using the following query:

```
[{
  "type": "/sports/sports_team",
  "name": null,
  "limit": 300,
  "league": [{
    "type": "/sports/sports_league_participation",
    "name": null
  }]
}]
```

You'll see that it returns some of the following teams; however, I would like to filter it by league; I only want NBA basketball teams.

```
{
  "name": "Detroit Pistons",
  "league": [{
    "name": null,
    "type": "/sports/sports_league_participation"
  }],
  "type": "/sports/sports_team"
},
{
  "name": "Detroit Lions",
  "league": [
    {
      "name": null,
      "type": "/sports/sports_league_participation"
    },
    {
      "name": null,
      "type": "/sports/sports_league_participation"
    },
    {
      "name": null,
      "type": "/sports/sports_league_participation"
    }
  ],
  "type": "/sports/sports_team"
},
{
  "name": "Detroit Tigers",
  "league": [{
    "name": null,
    "type": "/sports/sports_league_participation"
  }],
  "type": "/sports/sports_team"
},
{
  "name": "Detroit Red Wings",
  "league": [{
    "name": null,
    "type": "/sports/sports_league_participation"
  }],
  "type": "/sports/sports_team"
},
```

Note:  I have tried `"name":"National Basketball Association"`, etc. but nothing seems to work.

How can I filter FreeBase by league?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you

```
[{
  "type": "/sports/sports_team",
  "name": null,
  "limit": 300,
  "league": [{
    "type": "/sports/sports_league_participation",
    "/sports/sports_league_participation/league": [{
      "name": "National Basketball Association"
    }]
  }]
}]
```